# Django multisite multiple favicon.ico requests for a site

Tags: django

UPDATE: explicitly indicating it's running on development server, so answers/comments won't deviate to best practise of serving static files, which to me it's irrelevant to the problem since there is no favicon at all.

I have a django multisite setup running off the same code base **ON DEVELOPMENT SERVER**, site A and site B, for some reason, browsing to site A causes multiple requests to favicon.ico but not happening in site B.

log for site A browsing to /

```
125.236.233.243 - - [14/Jan/2014:14:41:13 +1300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 212 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
125.236.233.243 - - [14/Jan/2014:14:41:13 +1300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 212 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
125.236.233.243 - - [14/Jan/2014:14:41:13 +1300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 212 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
125.236.233.243 - - [14/Jan/2014:14:41:13 +1300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 212 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
125.236.233.243 - - [14/Jan/2014:14:41:14 +1300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 212 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
```

log for site B browsing to /

```
125.236.233.243 - - [14/Jan/2014:14:41:08 +1300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
```

I have compared the settings and there is no obvious reason why this would happen...

Here is the settings for site A

```
MEDIA_ROOT = join(VIRTUALENV_ROOT, 'public-www', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = join(VIRTUALENV_ROOT, 'public-www', 'static', 'sitea')

STATIC_URL = '/static/sitea/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 
    join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static', 'sitea'),
    join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ( 
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

And this is the settings for site B, which uses the settings from site A and overwrites some settings:

```
import os
from os.path import join, dirname

PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(dirname(__file__))
VIRTUALENV_ROOT = dirname(PROJECT_ROOT)

try:
    from settings import *
except: pass

SITE_ID = 2
SITE_NAME = 'siteb'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates', SITE_NAME),
    join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates', 'sitea'),
    join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = join(VIRTUALENV_ROOT, 'public-www', 'static', SITE_NAME)

STATIC_URL = '/static/{}/'.format(SITE_NAME)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static', SITE_NAME),
    join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static'),
)
```

What's even more interesting is, site C, has identical(almost except site name different) settings with site B, is having multiple favicon.ico requests. WEIRD.

Comment: Are the base templates different?

Comment: Are you serving static files through Django? Fav.ico should be served by Nginx or Apache, not Django.

Comment: @skip the base templates are the same

Comment: @Erasmose yes I am serving favicon through django on development server, the question is, why site B doesn't get the multiple requests.

Comment: @JamesLin  Django is not really built to serve static files. And your issue is probably a bug. It is recommended to use Nginx or Apache to serve those static files. It will make your life easier, believe me.

Comment: @Erasmose thank you for your advise, I believe you, I am also aware of that, like I said it's on a development server. On production server I will use nginx to serve static files directly, just like every other existing websites.